# Trying to find the longest chain of nonblank cells in Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, count, max

[image]

I'm trying to figure out the best/simplest way to get the desired outcome from a data set which looks like the images.
Cells A2:A40 are all autoincrementing by 1. When a value is deleted, a blank is introduced and a new autoincrement starts.

I would like to find a way to functionally program cell A1 to parse down the length of A2:A(last cell), and each time there is a blank, it will run a counta() and then it will take the max value of all those counts, and return the max streak. So if I decide to delete the value in cell A16, the new longest counta() would be 9 (from c28).

I don't need to see the values of each count (col C), I would just like to return the max() in A1.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure to understand your goal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ARRAYFORMULA into cell A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A40<>"",ROW(A2:A40)),IF(A2:A40="",ROW(A2:A40)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=if(A1="",MATCH(1,arrayformula(if(A2:A="",1,0)),0)-1,)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply and sorry for the confusion on my end goal. Your solution is very close to what I need, so I'm trying to repurpose it without column B showing up.
Essentially my end goal is just to have only column A with values on the sheet. CellA1 would have the formula. When I put your formula into A1, I get a cyclical dependency based on the first condition being "A1="""
I'm looking at the sheet titled "Stack Question" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G7Hsv_KklrIDpI2_GedUL-f5MbgPEmOstd5miDudyVs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've added some more columns to illustrate what I would like the end goal to be.
I am looking for the longest range of cells with no blanks. Essentially, I'll start off with 1 full column of uninterrupted auto incrementing cells. On any given day, I will delete a value in that column, which will restart the increment. I am looking to find the longest unbroken chain of cells in any given column